# Can we update a datapoint in Graphite using same timestamp?

Tags: graphite

Let's understand my usecase.

I want to store some point data along with time-series data in Graphite. I have some metric say ***user.12345.lastVisitedTimeInMs*** and I want to update it each time the user visited our site.
So, this information is not a time-series data but a point data.

Is it possible in Graphite to update a metric's value instead of putting another value with a new timestamp?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the design of graphite and it's fixed-size pre-allocated database whisper I would assume that you can update previously submitted data points of a metric for a given timestamp but I only used this flexibility to submit historical data after the fact for given timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely update a value for an existing timestamp/measurement.

Comment: Thanks. So, you mean if I have a value v1 for the timestamp t1 and I update the timestamp t1 with new value v2. Now when I fetch data for t1 will I get v1 and v2 both or just v2?